# Find Electric Field at certain radii for a sphere

Tags: electric-fields, charge, gauss-law

**If radius of non-conducting sphere is R=4cm, find Electric field at r1=3 cm (for inner Gaussian surface) and r2=6cm(for outer Gaussian surface)
Volume charge density is given as: ρ = c r^2 where  c is a constant**

The electric fields at r1 and r2 were found as

**E1 = ρ r1 / 3(ε0)** and

**E2= kq/r2^2**
What I can't figure out is how to calculate the value of enclosed charge

**q (enc) = ∮ ρ dV**
since c is unknown. If I put

**cr^2 =q enclosed /(4/3  * π * r^3),**

I still can't find q enclosed due to c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $c$ is unknown, then you don't know it and you'll have to leave it (either directly or in another form, like $\rho$ or $Q$) as a variable in your expressions. So indeed you can either replace $c$ with $\rho/r^2$ or $Q / (4\pi R^5/3)$, but you cannot eliminate it completely unless they ask for some problem with a very fortuitous cancellation.